# TinyMCE 4.3 - how to get Image Tools to save edited images as files

Tags: tinymce, image-uploading

I don't manage to get the Image Tools plugin to actually upload the images to the server. I upload images with the jbimages plugin with no problem. But when a picture is edited with the Image Tools, although there's the uploading bar, which gets to 100%, it seems that it's only uploaded as a blob. The page calls the tinymce.activeEditor.uploadImages() function when submitting the form data, but it doesn't work.

I use the 'postacceptor.php' file from the example (defined in 'images_upload_url') and the 'images_upload_base_path' is defined as well.

The files are not uploaded to the server, and the img src remains a blob.

What could the problem be?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What debugging have you done in your PHP code?  Is the code being triggered?  Does the file appear in the posted content?  You need to narrow down where in the process things are failing.

- Is the issue that TinyMCE is not posting the edited image or is the issue that the image is posted and the PHP code is not properly saving the image and returning valid JSON?
- How did you configure TinyMCE?
- Does an edited image get posted to your server code?

  - What is in that form post?
- If you disable the jbImages plugin does that change anything?

Without more details it will be very difficult to help you figure this out.